# Better way to select last row version in multi-column primarykey

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres table where the PK is made up of a UUID (id) and an integer (version).  Most queries want to select the latest version of a particular ID. The query I use now looks like this:

```
select * from dataset
where id = '0faa6a7b-587c-4106-9b1e-3cf155c2ee41' and 
version = (select max(version) from dataset where id = '0faa6a7b-587c-4106-9b1e-3cf155c2ee41')
```

I am wondering if there is a better, more efficient way of handling this type of query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use anti-joins,

here is an example, with returns the latest versions of all

```
SELECT
    d.*   
FROM
    "dataset" AS d
    LEFT JOIN "dataset" As d_ ON d_."id" = d."id" AND d_."version" > d."version"
WHERE
    d_."id" IS NULL
;
```

this query also provides you speed, if you have an index on version field too. also you can filter whatever you want.

Comment: Interesting, this one would provide more flexibility as it allows other filters.  I just tried it on a 2 million row table and using 3 ORs against LEFT JOINed tables, I got results back in 95ms.  Not bad.  I am going to have to look at this one some more.

Comment: i use this method in all my queries. i don't know what i would do, if there is no such a method :)

Answer (score 4):

Which method is the fastest depends on indexes and data distribution. The *shortest* (and often fastest) in PostgreSQL is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) *
FROM   dataset
WHERE  id = '0faa6a7b-587c-4106-9b1e-3cf155c2ee41'
ORDER  BY id, version DESC;
```

Can be expanded to fetch multiple rows with the latest version at once.
For just a single row, this will do, too:

```
SELECT *
FROM   dataset
WHERE  id = '0faa6a7b-587c-4106-9b1e-3cf155c2ee41'
ORDER  version DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

The perfect index for the case would be a [multi-column index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) like:

```
CREATE INDEX dataset_id_version_idx ON dataset(id, version DESC);
```

More about `DISTINCT ON`:

[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)